# How can I reduce lagging with GUI/GPU stuff -- make Unity run smaller, quicker, faster?

Tags: gui, gpu

Finally installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Pavilion 2000. Have all of my apps on and loaded and am happy thus far.

ONE ISSUE -- I'm experiencing a small amount of GUI/GPU style lagging when I go to open menus, move windows, etc.

What settings can I disable to allow it to run sharply and quickly, even if i t means sacrificing some of the graphics?

Have already installed pre-load. Just want the OS to run sharply and quickly with menu refreshes, window moves, etc. I do not mind sacrificing graphics.

Somone mentionted to me I have to install video drivers but the two that come up in system settings under drivers it won't let  me install.

ALSO : I am driving a second 19" monitor -- would that make a difference performance wise as well?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try Unity 2D.
When you're at login screen and you have to put in your password, on the right of your name there is an Ubuntu logo. Click on it and then select The 2D option. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind replacing Unity you could install Lubuntu. Seeing as you have Ubuntu installed you can just do `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`, logout then login and select Lubuntu or another of the newly installed options.

Answer (score 0):

When I want speed I use openbox. I use it on Ubuntu 12.04 and the UI responds really fast.
However, you'll need a lot of time to set it up to your liking.

And, a few things won't work.

But it *will* run fast.