# What is the standard text editor in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, text-editor, default-programs

What is the standard text editor for GNOME in Ubuntu?

(I tried searching for it on Google, but did not find the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: gedit.

To launch from terminal to create a new file just type `gedit`, or to edit an existing file, type `gedit myFile.txt`.
You can also open multiple files at once into different gedit tabs, just by appending the other files to the command, for example:`gedit myFile1.txt ~/myFile2.c /tmp/myFile3.tex`

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 3):

Ever since GNOME 42, GNOME's default text editor app is [Text Editor](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.TextEditor/), instead of [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit). Yes, that is a confusing name for a text editor, as it makes it hard to distinguish from other text editors.

[image: Screenshot of website]

Ubuntu 22.10 ships with GNOME Text Editor. You can install this editor on the command-line like this:

```
sudo apt install gnome-text-editor
```

Its executable name is also `gnome-text-editor`.

Answer (score 0):

As [AlexP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867670/what-is-the-standard-text-editor-in-gnome#comment1343017_867670) and [Danyc0](https://askubuntu.com/a/867679/22949) say, the main graphical text editor in a GNOME-based system is Gedit.

- [Gedit project home page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit)
- [Gedit page on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit)
- [Gedit on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit)

Gedit is installed by default in all [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME)-based Ubuntu systems (until Ubuntu 22.10), and not just [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/) (which uses [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell)). In particular, since [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/) is [really a shell for GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/a/254449/22949), systems that use Unity as their default interface ship Gedit, too.

The [MATE desktop environment](http://mate-desktop.org/), used by [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), is [based on GNOME 2, but forked from it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)) and [the names (and executables) for the main apps are different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)#Software_components). Ubuntu MATE thus ships [Pluma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluma_(editor)) rather than Gedit. Since [Pluma is a fork of Gedit from GNOME 2](https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma/blob/master/README) (not GNOME 3), the version of Gedit that Pluma is based on is older than the version of Gedit present in flavors of Ubuntu that use Unity or GNOME Shell.

Comment: This answer is out of date.